# undo [Use Service] - Manage multiple Spring Boot run configurations in the Services tool window

Tags: spring-boot, intellij-idea, view, service

In IntelliJ IDEA pop-up appeared

[image]

> Manage multiple Spring Boot run configurations in the Services tool window

After pressing [Use Service] Spring Boot apps are run inside Service view

[image]

As we have 1 app per repository, this IDEA functionality does not have much sense.
How to disable or undo Use Services view ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove it using this context menu:

[image: remove]

Comment: Actually type here is `SpringBootApplicationConfigurationType`, so this removes all Spring Boot apps.